# Can I restore a deleted Task Item?

Tags: 2013, restore, task-list

I know I can restore the Task List itself because it remains in the recycle bin.

If I create a Task Item within a Task List using SharePoint 2013, can I restore that deleted Task Item?

Thanks

Comment: The same would apply for an item. have you checked the recycle bin?

Comment: check it also at recycle bin

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed, you can recover any deleted list item from the user Recycle Bin at: `/_layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx`

But if you deleted the item from the user Recycle Bin, there's another view called the Admin Recycle Bin that many end users will not know that exists, recovering from here will send the item back to the location from whence it was originally deleted. It's located at:
`/_layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx?View=2`

Answer (score 0):

I see I can indeed restore my deleted Task Items. Just like deleted Task Lists, the Task Items are in the Recycle Bin. All I have to do is select the Task Item and click Restore Selection.